# Can't open SQL Server Reporting Services Home

Tags: sql-server

I've installed SQL Server BI for Visual Studio 2012. Also I was setting SQL Server Reporting Services Configuration Manager.

I set Report Manager URL to :
http://labalumit:80/Reports-MyReport

But when I try to open this url from web browser, it says:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Reports-MyReport was not found on this server.

I don't know exactly what the problem here, because I was following the tutorial to install SQL Server BI correctly.

Did I miss something during the installation? Or do I have to install localhost like xampp or others?

Comment: @MitchWheat: i dont know. The url just show me not found page.

Comment: what happens if you open that url using a browser on the server itself?

Comment: @Paolo: what do you mean by 'on the server itself' ?
i opened the url using IE and chrome. but it alwys say http not found

Comment: you can reach a url browsing from your pc, from the pc of a colleague or from the server hosting the site the url is referring to. what happens when you fire up the browser on the server machine on which you installed SSRS and try to browse the SSRS url from that machine?